# What is the difference between an operator and a clause in SQL?

Tags: sql

What is the difference between an operator and a clause in SQL?

I have googled about this but I can't get any information other than examples of them. For example, why is the DISTINCT clause a 'clause' but not an operator? I feel like operator and clause are interchangeable words. Please advise on this basic question, thank you!!

Comment: Gordon's answer is spot on, but to address `DISTINCT`, it doesn't operate on it's own. It's only valid when used in conjunction with `SELECT`. `SELECT` and `SELECT DISTINCT` are two different versions of the `SELECT` clause of a statement. Hope that helps clarify.

Answer (score 3):

A `SELECT` statement consists of a series of clauses.  The most commonly used are:

- `SELECT` (which introduces the statement)
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `FETCH`

Within a clause, there are various syntactic elements, such as expressions and `JOIN` conditions.  "Operators" manipulate data.  You might think of them as syntactic sugar for functions.  They fall into various categories, such as:

- Comparison operators, such as `=`, `like`, and `exists`.
- Boolean operators, such as `and` and `not`.
- Arithmetic operators, such as `+` and `*`.
- Set operators, such as `union all`.
- String operators, such as `||`.

I also consider `join`s to be operators that are specific to the `from` clause.  I'm not 100% sure that is standard nomenclature.